# Windows 7 load from GRUB 2.02 beta, Fatal System Error

Tags: multi-boot, grub2, windows-7, boot

So, I have a dual boot pc, with Ubuntu on one disk, and Windows 7 on another, in a separate partition.
A couple of days ago, I tried to log in to Windows, and have been getting this message ever since:

STOP: c000021a {Fatal System Error}
The initial session process or system process terminated unexpectedly with a status of 0x00000000 (0xc0000428 0x00010488)
The system has been shut down.

I tried the repair procedures suggested on various sites, using a Windows installation cd, but nothing seems to work.
The only things that have changed lately are that I've reconnected my dvd player, but that was a few days back, and Windows started up just fine after, and downloaded and installed updates for Ubuntu.
I changed nothing under Windows.

I'm no computer wiz, and really don't know what I should do. Any help would be great.
Thanks

Comment: See for instance http://support.microsoft.com/kb/156669 STOP errors are internal Windows errors and your solution will also be Windows related. Ubuntu is not going  to be the answer to your problem unless you want to delete your Windows or make a backup of your NTFS partition.

Answer (score 0):

are you getting to windows i mean can you access windows now? if yes then install EasyBCD 2.2.0.182 dual boot Windows 7/8 download it from any torrent website and make dual boot your system. i think your bootmgr is not working correctly

Comment: Thanks for writing back.
I was thinking about using Ubuntu to access my files, back them up on an external HD, and reinstall Windows, but I know that would/could mess up the GRUB, so I'm hoping to find a different fix. I cannot access Windows, I'm afraid. It crashes while the OS is still starting up.
I could try accessing in safe mode, though I don't know if that might help.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar only I redid my computer put fresh copy of Windows 7 on and left 100GB for Ubuntu. Only Ubuntu didn't take all 100GB so I re-sized the windows partition to have all unused space I ended up having the same problems you did. I re-installed Ubuntu so it could reconfigure the partition table. Everything works now

Comment: I'm somewhat terrified of playing around with Ubuntu, as this is now my only functioning OS on this pc. If nothing else works, I'll reinstall windows, and use a live Linux cd to fix the GRUB, which should, I've been told, go to hell in the process.

Comment: ya it is a bit unnerving when things dont work. Windows should be fine it should just be the boot loader that is corrupt. I would install a distro on a usb drive using yumi multiboot creator just in case